# I have a project in laravel with scss and css files. I am new to scss

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a project in laravel with scss and css files. I am new to scss. I have just created a scss file but the problem is that is automatically created the css file in the same directory but i want that css file should be in the css folder. Here is my folder structure.
[image: As you see my folder structure (blade laravel) i have already scss and css folders]

I cannot figure out how to put scss files and css file separately.

Comment: Why not just move the file to the directory you want it in?

Comment: but it again regenerate the same file again

Comment: Have you ran any laravel mix commands?